# AngularJs set radio button default from ngValue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of items that generates a list of radio buttons using ngValue because i need to ngModel to hold the entire object I have.
The thing is that when I reload the route, the selected item that was saves exists in the ngModel but the radio button won't be marked as checked.

Any suggestions how to do it beside on the init to check if the ngModel already filled and reassign to it manually?

Comment: See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/dzynjfbn/1/

Comment: In your fiddle you're manually assigning one of the items in the array to your model. I asked for a way without doing it, lets say you get the model from a service already filled with the default option

Comment: okay - if you have a complex object, you will need to iterate of each key/value of teh object to make sure it matches, and select the index of the matched object in your array. See updated plunkr: https://jsfiddle.net/dzynjfbn/3/

Comment: I hoped angular would know how to do it out of the box, with me having to iterate over the array and check it.